# react-admin edit wait for response

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin to update DB via internal API (not directly from the server react-admin is talking to).

The API call can fail due to various reasons.

Therefore, I want to hold the edit page until it gets the response from the server which is waiting for the response from the internal API.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set its `mutationMode` to `pessimistic`.

Extract from the documentation:

The `<Edit>` view exposes two buttons, Save and Delete, which perform “mutations” (i.e. they alter the data). React-admin offers three modes for mutations. The mode determines when the side effects (redirection, notifications, etc.) are executed:

-`pessimistic`: The mutation is passed to the dataProvider first. When the dataProvider returns successfully, the mutation is applied locally, and the side effects are executed.

-`optimistic`: The mutation is applied locally and the side effects are executed immediately. Then the mutation is passed to the dataProvider. If the dataProvider returns successfully, nothing happens (as the mutation was already applied locally). If the dataProvider returns in error, the page is refreshed and an error notification is shown.

-`undoable` (default): The mutation is applied locally and the side effects are executed immediately. Then a notification is shown with an undo button. If the user clicks on undo, the mutation is never sent to the dataProvider, and the page is refreshed. Otherwise, after a 5 seconds delay, the mutation is passed to the dataProvider. If the dataProvider returns successfully, nothing happens (as the mutation was already applied locally). If the dataProvider returns in error, the page is refreshed and an error notification is shown.